# Is there a way to use polymer-dart with Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dart, dart-polymer

#### What's the easiest way to use polymer-dart with ruby on rails or on other frame works currently?

Using vulcanize and polymer-rails gem and some hack, I'm trying to take care of html imports.
But I'm having hard time resolving file urls.

> GET http://localhost:3000/assets/paper_ripple_behavior.dart

What is happening seems some polymer scripts trying to fetch dart scripts using url relative to the location of self or expecting the dart server. Since it's vulcanized, and processed, and on RoR, it never finds what it wants(Maybe I should just clone the packages and rewrite all the links, easier).
Or if there are no duplicate names, I could make all files available at localhost:3000/assets/
Some funcitons also seems to be doing something like the below:

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: Unable to find library at http://localhost:3000/assets/shadow.dart.
Stack Trace:
#0      InitializationCrawler.InitializationCrawler (package:initialize/src/mirror_loader.dart:43:31)
#1      loadInitializers (package:initialize/src/mirror_loader.dart:16:14)
#2      run (package:initialize/initialize.dart:27:24)
#3      run.<run_async_body> (package:web_components/src/mirror_initializer.dart:26:11)
#4      Future.Future.microtask.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:144)
#5      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43)
#6      _microtaskLoopEntry (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52)
#7      _ScheduleImmediateHelper._handleMutation (dart:html:42567)
undefined:1 undefined
```

At this point, I'm considering to run RoR and dart on different ports and redirecting some request to dart Server, though I don't know if it's practical.


How would you let dart play with RoR?

### Edit

After few days of tinkering, I came to a conclusion that Günter Zöchbauer is probably right for the time being.
While

1. rewriting embedded html import hrefs in the html files found under the packages directory
2. tinkering with html import urls (element.href found in initialize method in the file "web_components-0.12.0+4/lib/html_import_annotation.dart" was taking care of this)

seem to solve some of the html import url issues, embedded scripts are still attempting to load dart file directly under assets: "http://localhost:3000/assets/paper_button.dart ". 
"initPolymer()" also  attempts to load dependency files in a similar fashion, at least in "/components/packages/initialize/src/mirror_loader.dart".
These are discordant behavior with the other dart libraries, so hopefully will change in the future versions.
As things stand now, understanding and finding loader scripts is too much for me, although I believe more skilled programmers would find it a breeze.

Comment: Is this Polymer 1.0.0-rc.x or 0.16.x?

Comment: There is a know issue with (non-dart-source) resource files in Polymer `1.0.0-rc.x`, where the paths are resolved wrongly.

Comment: Hi  Günter Zöchbauer. I was using polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.6. As the answer to the question, your "only as a static asset" seems right which is pretty much "No, you can't" because the use case defies the rails' purpose. Do you mind if I keep the question open?

Comment: I don't know Rails, but if you explain a bit I might be able to provide a helpful answer. How does that defy rails' purpose? A Polymer.dart application doesn't support to be modified after `pub build` and `pub build` is the only way to create a deployable. The only thing that can be modified after build is not-inlined CSS. Element templates HTML is all inlined AFAIK even though the individual files are written to the build output directory - this is only a current limitation of `pub`.

Comment: Nothing complicated. For serving static files, RoR is...well, not ideal. As to "pub build is the only way to create a deployable",  we have dart2js and html, dart, css are different assets, in theory it's possible to modify non-component html documents dynamically. hmm, I've just had an idea I could just pub build, then edit the entry point html file into an erb template and move it to my view folder...why did not I think of this?

Comment: This way might work. Yup, `pub build` runs `dart2js` but with Polymer `dart2js` alone is not enough. In production there is no Dart, there is no browser that runs Dart code (Dartium is not supposed to be used in production).

Answer (score 0):

For deployment you need to run `pub build` in the Dart package and serve the result (`build/web`) from your server. You can't serve Dart source.
If you use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter there shouldn't be any `*.dart` files be fetched.

For development use a server that redirects requests for Dart resources to `pub serve`.

Answer (score 0):

Yay, I've found a way.

#### Purpose

Use dart-polymer tags and run an application written in dart on rails server.

#### Method

Through making necessary resources available at RailsAppRoot/pub and editing views/layout/application.html.erb

#### How to do

1. Create a simple application on webstorm or intellij that make use of polymer tags you would like to use in your rails application.
2. Modify the links in your app to fetch resources relative to the url root.
3. Copy the contents of the web folder, dart_app_project_name/build/web, into
   rails_app_root/pub
4. You might also need to copy the lib folder
5. Copy the header and the scripts found in your entry point html file of your dart app into "application.html.erb" or use render partial.
6. Use the polymer tags anywhere.

For the step 2 you can use something like this:

```
require 'pry'  
require 'pry-doc'    
require 'pry-byebug' 
require 'nokogiri'
def prepend_slash file 
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open(file).read())
  doc.search("link[rel='import']").each do |node|
    href = node['href']
    next if href.nil?
    node['href'] ="/"+ href if href[0] != "/"
  end
  doc.search("script").each do |n|
    src = n['src']
    next if src.nil?
    n['src'] = "/"+src if src[0] != "/"
  end
  File.open(file,'w').write doc.to_html
end

target = 'path_to_your_app/app/views/layouts/_polymer_body.html.erb'
prepend_slash(target)
p "processed"
```

Your app and rails server can communicate using json or simply by embedding data in html document, so in theory dart-polymer and rails now can have fun together.
 
If Turbolinks is giving you troubles, try something like:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;
void onReady(var callback){
    var d = js.context.callMethod(r'$',[document]);
    d.callMethod('on',['page:change']);
}
```